# Exim4 - set EHLO to mail from domain

Tags: email, smtp, exim

How to set EHLO to the domain in the from/envelope-from domain?

The SMTP server will send mails from different domains like @mydomain1.com, @mydomain2.com etc

How to set the EHLO to the specifik domain?

Comment: why?  most hosts want EHLO to match the rDNS

Comment: So how do I set the EHLO to `smtp.mydomain.com` without setting `/etc/hostname` ? Where in the config can I set the hostname?

Comment: you can set `primary_hostname` in main configuration. that might be better,

Comment: http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-main_configuration.html

Comment: https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/4405084705559-How-to-enable-custom-mail-HELOs seems to offer a solution. I don't know if it's specific to cPanel.

Answer (score 0):

`ehlo_name` is an expanded parameter of the SMTP transport, if you set `max_mail` to 1 then $sender_address will defined and you can use that in the expansion.

this seems like a really dumb idea. don't do it.

Comment: It might be dumb to do this. But I want to set EHLO to a predifined value so I don't have to set `/etc/hostname`.. I just want to set the hostname in the config.. Have tried everything but havn't found a solution yet

Comment: In which file can I set `ehlo_name` ?

Comment: whichever file configures exim, if you are using debian's split config, the file with the apropriate smtp transport definition

Comment: Have tried everything. Could you please be more specific?

Comment: not without more detail, what OS, what exim version etc.

Comment: `Exim version 4.92 ` on `Debian Buster`.. I have found the variable `MAIN_HARDCODE_PRIMARY_HOSTNAME` which seems to be the "simplest" way to hardcode the hostname, but haven't found the right file to put it. Even after restart of exim4 it doesn't have any affect

Comment: you need to say somethig like `MAIN_HARDCODE_PRIMARY_HOSTNAME =example.com` you can either edit it into the start of  `/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template` or add a file to /etc/exim4/conf.d/main/ with a name before `02` with that content and run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config` and say  yes to the 'split config' option (the last question I think)  it's only the 'DC_' values in exim config that have external sources.